# Is it possible to specify the bash prompt using a command-line option?

Tags: bash, vim, command-line

I use vim a lot and often find it useful to drop into the command line using `!bash`.
However, I need to type `exit` to return to vim and sometimes I'm not sure whether I'm in a subshell or whether that will close my session.

What I'd really like to do is type something like `!bash -prompt "subshell"` so that I get something like this:

```
subshell$ <commands go here>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most direct way to do this is to set the `PS1` environment variable within vim:

```
:let $PS1="subshell$ "
```

And start your sub-shells using the command `:shell` instead of `:!bash`.

Using the `$` sign with `let` modifies an environment variable. Add this to your *.vimrc* to persist the setting.

Alternately, using `:shell` you *can* specify a more specific command, including arguments, using the *shell option*, see `help shell` and `help 'shell'`.

So:

```
:set shell=bash\ --rcfile\ ~/.vimbashrc
```

In *.vimbashrc* add `PS1="subshell "`, and invoke the sub-shells using `:shell` instead of `!bash`. Add this to your *.vimrc* to persist the setting.

So you have two options:

- Add `let $PS1="subshell "` to your *.vimrc*, and start sub-shells using `:shell` instead of `:!bash`.
- Make a custom rc file for your vim sub-shells, add your specific `PS1="subshell "` to it, and modify the `shell` option in your *.vimrc*: `set shell=bash\ --rcfile\ ~/.vimbashrc`.

Finally, if you must use `:!bash` to start the sub-shells there are a couple of more options. Note that you can also pass a more specific command line using `!`, e.g.:

- `:PS1="subshell$ " bash` should work.
- `:!bash\ --rcfile\ ~/.vimbashrc`, and set `PS1` in *.vimbashrc* as above

But you'll need to type these *every time*, or define a mapping for it.

Comment: This doesn't work- starting a new bash shell won't pass the current env variables into it!

Comment: Cool, this works well. I also added `. ~/.bashrc` to the top of `~/.vimbashrc` so that I still get my normal bash settings.

Comment: @RobertMaysJr what doesn't work? Using `let` to set `PS1`, and then launching using `:shell` should work for you, have you tried it?

Comment: you changed your answer after I commented to add the stuff about :shell - don't play stupid.

Comment: His answer says he wants to use 'bash' in which case your solution wouldn't work - I tried it.  After you added the stuff about :shell then use, it would work.. and you stole my answer for part 3 (about --rcfile which I answered 15 mins before your edit to add it)

Comment: @RobertMaysJr I'm not _playing_ anything, I'm commenting on my answer. I did edit the answer, it's part of the public edit history for anyone to review. The bit about using `shell` was part of the original answer as well, and appears to be useful to the OP

Comment: Wow, so you can just edit your answer to include the correct info from other people and get the points? That's freak'n lame.

Comment: @RobertMaysJr anyone with enough rep can edit answers, including mine and yours. If you find something incorrect in my answer, I invite you to fix it yourself.

Comment: @RobertMaysJr If you read the StackOverflow community rules -- it's explicitly desired that the upvoted answers be as useful as possible. Synthesizing information from others is helpful towards this goal. Keep in mind that the goal isn't just to score as many points as possible for oneself, but to create a knowledge base that acts as a shared community resource.

Answer (score 5):

Use shell variable `$SHLVL` seems to be another option here.  Add `$SHLVL` in your `$PS1`:

```
export PS1="$PS1 $SHLVL"
```

so your prompt looks like this:

```
[tim@RackAblade47 ~]$ 2
```

when you start shell from VIM, `$SHLVL` will increase:

```
[tim@RackAblade47 ~]$ 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can change the prompt inside the shell before running your commands

PS1="subshell"

checkout this guide for all the options http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html

If you really must do it via the bash command you can use '--rcfile' to specify an RC file that runs the PS1 command for you  (you usually put the PS1= line your .bashrc to customize the prompt at login)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question, you can say inside Vim:

```
:!VIMPROMPT="(vim) " bash
```

and change your prompt (in your .bashrc, presumably) from something like

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

to

```
PS1='$VIMPROMPT\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

this will change your prompt from

```
me@host:~$
```

to

```
(vim) me@host:~$
```

if run inside Vim.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally using

```
case $(ps $PPID) in *vim|*bash)
  PS1="$(ps $PPID | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 1d) $PS1" ;;
esac
```

in my [prompt script](https://github.com/estebank/environment/blob/master/fancy_prompt.sh#L124) that's sourced by [my .bashrc](https://github.com/estebank/environment/blob/master/bashrc.sh), taken from [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273393/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-bash-prompt-using-a-command-line-option#comment-16510910).

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to change the prompt for a vim subshell process by checking for the `MYVIMRC` variable which is exported inside vim, and will then update `PS1` accordingly. I updated my `.bashrc` file with the following.

```sh
PS1='\$ '
# when in vim subshell change PS1 for clarity
if [[ $MYVIMRC ]]; then PS1='>> '; fi;
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this in your `.bashrc` after any existing `PS1=` statements.

```
if ps | grep -q vim; then
  export PS1="[VIM]$PS1"
fi
```

Tested on Ubuntu.

Comment: This isn't very robust, but I was meaning to propose something similar.  Instead of just grepping for `vim`, check if it is the parent of your current shell.  `case $(ps $PPID) in *vim) PS1="[VIM] $PS1" ;; esac`

Answer (score -2):

You can send it to the background with CTRL+Z and then bring it back with the `fg` command. With `jobs` you see all the jobs you have stopped.

This was you can have multiple instances of vim in parallel and chose which one you want to bring back. If there's no running you will just get a `no current job` error and that's it.

This doesn't specifically answer your question, but addresses the problem underneath it.